# Eclipse does not recognize some valid attributes and tags

Tags: html, eclipse, svg

Take this html (ignoring placeholder values "..."):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
<title>...</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
<svg class="..." width="..." height="...">  
    <path transform="..." d="..." />  
</svg>   
</body>  
</html>
```

Eclipse EE is giving me the warnings

```
- undefined attribute name (width)  
- undefined attribute name (height)  
- unknown tag (path)
```

Oddly, the output seems fine although I am not sure why it is doing this. Can anyone provide any insight?

Edit: as an addendum, the Eclipse EE internet browser almost never draws svg graphics correctly for me, but when I use Firefox or Google Chrome for testing, the content displays correctly. Is this related?

Comment: Eclipse EE browser uses IE internally

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. Looking up the issues IE has with SVG helped answer some of my questions, but there is still the issue with Eclipse not recognizing the tags.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Make sure that your eclipse is updated. The eclipse website states that any versions prior to 3.7 contain IE7, which does not display HTML5 tags correctly, rather than IE9.

If your eclipse is updated, however, you can always configure eclipse to use an external browser like Firefox or Chrome.

Edit:
I did some research and learned that eclipse checks tags and attributes against the doctype, so with your declaration, it will not understand HTML5 tags and attributes.